# Where is my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was given a house by Ulfric Stormcloak as a reward for my services to the rebellion. I remember the Jarl of Whiterun (after the capture) offered me a home, but I cannot find it. Does anyone know where this house is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the Jarl offered you the possibility to buy some house. You must talk to its associate to get one.

Comment: That is correct you have to by it from his Steward for 5k gold. It comes with a bed and a chest, but that is about it, until you use money to by more stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Jarl offers you the opportunity to *buy* a property if you choose to. You just have to talk to his associate. She is the dunmer woman with whom you talk to when first entering the Jarl's home in the beginning of the game.

Comment: If this is supposed to be about Whiterun, it's false. You need to talk to his advisor, Avinicci, the blacksmith's father.

Comment: So the whole fact Ulfric offered me a house was a lie? :o

Comment: Ulfric offers you the ability to purchase a house in Whiterun, not an actual house.

Comment: @PerishableDave No... Ulfric doesn't. You are thinking about the Jarl of Whiterun. Ulfric has nothing to do with the house in Whiterun. But you are correct in the fact the Jarl of Whiterun simply offers you the ability to. And Prospector Avinicci is who you speak with to buy it.

Comment: @JClaspill whoops, you're right. So many uncommon non-english names in this game I get confused. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

The house in Whiterun is second on the right after you enter the main gate. It's just past Warmaiden's. This is the house that the Jarl allows you to by, it is called 'Breezehome' on the map.

I haven't played up through the Stormcloak storyline, so I can't comment there.

Comment: Possibly, but when I check, I don't have the key. I do remember a possible side quest when given the home.

Comment: yeah, that is the house you'd need to buy. A far as I know, there isn't a gifted house in Whiterun.

Answer (score 1):

Ulfric says his steward will give you a house as a reward for liberating Hjaalmark (I may have spelled that wrong), but when you talk to the steward, he offers the sale (for 12000, not 5000) of a house.

Answer (score 0):

It's the next house up from Warmaiden's.  The house is called Breezehome, the price is 5000 gold, and if you want to upgrade it, it costs another 1500 gold.  That puts a potion making table and also the whole house is rigged out; beds, food, etc.